# OnCollisonEnter2D not triggering despite collision taking place

Tags: unity

I have been following a Unity basics tutorial and have run into a problem with trying to bring up the Game Over screen when a collision occurs. The bird (it's a Flappy Bird game) collides with the pipe and the collision occurs but my function doesn't trigger.

Here's my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class birdscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
    public float flapStrength = 1;
    public LogicScript logic;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicScript>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.up * flapStrength;
        }
    }
    void OnCollisonEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Bird collision detected!");
        logic.gameOver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how this object is set up in the hierarchy and inspector? Common issues: collider set to isTrigger, script not on the same object as the Rigidbody component, rigidbody set to Kinematic... Do you see anything in your debug console?

Answer (score 2):

The collision does not happen because you have a spelling mistake in your code. The correct method name is `OnCollisionEnter2D` and not `OnCollisonEnter2D`. Once you fixed that one, the obvious error should be gone.

If it still does not work afterwards, other common mistakes are (credit to DMGregory)

- collider set to isTrigger
- script not on the same object as the Rigidbody component
- rigidbody set to Kinematic

Comment: Oh gosh I left "typo in the method signature" out of my list of common issues because I read the code and didn't spot one. Good eye!